# Sum of a attribute at different points with the same coordinate

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I am quite new to ArcGIS.

I want to know how can I sum the number of different assets at the same point in a table as follows.

[image]

As a result, I want to have a table as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Dissolve with Lat and Long as Dissolve Fields and number field (SUM) as statistics:

[image]

[image]